# Laser reading not between range_min and range_max!

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, nav2d, turtlebot3, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i'm trying to use nav2d package on turtlebot3 for autonomous exploration(third tutorial). When i launch it, everything seems to work, except for the fact that rqt_console shows the warning "Laser reading not between range_min and range_max!".
Looking the messages published on /scan topic it says range max is 3.5 meters and actually some reading goes beyond this distance. The point is: how can i modify that value? Because i've tried modifying in Sensor.cpp the Custom laser range, but that doesn't work and also on yaml files i don't find any parameter referring to my laser range.
Thanks for help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293545/laser-reading-not-between-range_min-and-range_max!/) by [ryuzaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/34564/ryuzaki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According the specification of the [laser scan message](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) any depth measurements outside of the min-max range should be treated as erroneous and ignored.

As such I would assume these warnings can be safely ignored.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryuzaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/34564/ryuzaki/) on 2018-06-10**:
Thanks for your answer. That's what i've done in the end and  actually everything works. Just out of curiosity, is there any way to modify that or it's a way to prevent possible readings' inaccurancy beyond laser's range_max?